# How to make Ajax Requests on Mobile Devices using mySQL

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript

I'm new to ajax and I would like to make all of my textboxes submit to my MySQL database without an update page.

This works fine if I capture the value of the textbox with js as the parameter "str" ("type" is just another parameter i'm using)

```
function sendAjax(type, str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtResp").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtResp").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }


switch(type)
{
case 'search':
    xmlhttp.open("GET","mysql_process_search.php?q="+str,true);
  break;
case 'add':
    xmlhttp.open("GET","mysql_process_event.php?q="+str,true); 
  break;
}

xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And with the page mysql_process_event.php I get the proper results on a ***Desktop browser*** using:

```
echo $_GET['q'];
$q = $_GET['q'];

$con = mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("xxx", $con);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Events (Title)
VALUES ('".$q."')");

mysql_close($con);
```

**But this does not work on Mobile Safari or Mobile Android. It will capture the echoed response in the xml.responseText object fine and display it on the page, but it will not communicate with the database.**

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error message you receive? If you call the php page directly, you should be able be able to see the end-result, even on a mobile device.

Secondly, your code, as written, is inherently dangerous and wide open to SQL Injection, which means that it would be simple to hack your database and do bad things (like selecting everything from it, dropping tables, etc.). You want to be using bind variables, preferably, and escaping your string at the least.

Comment: Yes I know I wanted to simplify the php code so I could find the issue with mobile browsers. Thing is, there is no error, it just won't send or display information from the database. Works fine on desktop browsers

Comment: @TaylorMac Good; that concerned me. Next thoughts: Try turning up error reporting ( error_reporting(E_NOTICE); ) and see what you get. If there's any error at all, it should be shown. Second, I'm curious why you are using InnerHTML? I would suggest document.getElementById("...").value=response. Third, what desktop browsers have you tried it in? Fourth, is this on a public webhost? If you want, I could tried it on my iDevice and see if anything different happens.

Comment: Thanks alot. I allowed for more error reporting and I found my issue. On one of my HTML objects I did not have onclick="" so it would not work on mobile safari. It displayed that no request was being sent. Yes I'll have to change that innerHTML to .value.